# Manga/Manhua/Manwha Where the female lead is in a world where her day keeps repeating with zombies

Tags: story-identification, manga

In the story, our mc is the female lead of, I think, a story. Her day repeats over and over again and she can't see other people, only the male lead (which turns into a zombie). She finds out that the first infection comes from the bus. She can't see people, they're just "black" silhouettes. If they're infected they turn red. The only way she can actually see people is if she wins their trust. One scene that I remember is that a random "extra" saves her, but she is killed by people before our MC figures out who she was. Our MC resets each time she dies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[Surviving Romance](https://webtoon.fandom.com/wiki/Surviving_Romance)*.

> When Chaerin Eun becomes the protagonist of the romance novel she is
> reading, she expects a fairytale ending with the novel’s love
> interest, Jeha. But when a bizarre twist makes her realize the story
> is not playing out as it does in the book, she’ll need the help of an
> unlikely character from her class to defy the new storyline and find
> her happy ending -- if only she can figure out who this ‘Unknown
> Extra’ is first!

The NPCs are black blurry shapes until infected.

> [image]

Posted online by the creator [here](https://www.webtoons.com/en/horror/survive-romance/list?title_no=2607).